# Violation of primary key constraint duplicate key

Tags: c#, sql, ado

When running my tests to insert an account i stumble upon the error:

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Accounts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Accounts'."

I am aware that im inserting a duplicate but i can't figure out how to solve this. I already tried using the scope_identity but im not sure if im using it right.

PS: I cannot change the database.

```
 private static SqlCommand CreateInsertCommand(Account account, SqlConnection connection)
    {

        string insertStatement =
            "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Accounts ON " +
            "INSERT INTO Accounts " +
            "(Id, AccountNumber, Balance, AccountType, CustomerId) " +
            "VALUES (@Id, @AccountNumber, @Balance, @AccountType, @CustomerId) " +
            "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() " + // gets id from inserted account
            "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Accounts OFF";

        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);

        if (account.Id == 0)
        {
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", account.Id);
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to get a duplicate conflict, don't insert a duplicate. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Does the schema indicate that the key is auto-generated? If so, then don't include the Id. If not, then how are you determining the Id?

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery returns a value indicating the number of rows that changed.  You have an Insert Query which will return zero if the key is already in the table.  So the you have to use an Update to change value.  If you use Update and the returned value is zero (the key isn't in the table) then you have to use Insert.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Hey Camilo it's not me that's inserting the duplicates. I'm the one who needs to solve it if someone tries to do it. The tests i am running are tests that are created by my teachers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'solve'? What is the desired outcome? Most programs would catch the error and display a message to the user to say that the Id is already in use (or they wouldn't let the user specify the Id in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you simply want `update`?

```
update accounts
    set AccountNumber = @AccountNumber,
        Balance = @Balance,
        AccountType = @AccountType,
        CustomerId = @CustomerId
    where id = @id;
```

Comment: Hey i don't think this i what im searching for. I am running tests that are created by my teachers. When they try to put in a duplicate (a new account) i need to try and solve it. I can't figure out how.  thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

`IDENTITY_INSERT` allows you to specify a value for a field that is normally auto-generated. It doesn't let you create a duplicate.

You either need to delete the duplicate first, then use IDENTITY_INSERT to specify the value that you want - or just edit the existing row.